# jQuery validation no of error count number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I am currently working on jQuery validation; the current code I have was working fine, I am getting the number of error count. But I am not getting when the user enter the value in the corresponding field the error count has to detect one by one.

For example if I have 5 fields are not entered by the user it should say **You have missed 5 fields. Please fill before submitted** when all fields are entered the error field has to disable. And I need to highlight the label of the radio input when nothing is selected. Moreover I am trying to change my mandatory star from black to red. That is also not happening.

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#basicForm").validate({

    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
          var message = errors == 1
            ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
            : 'You have missed ' + errors + ' fields. Please fill before submitted.';
          $("#error_message").html(message);
          $(".error_msge").show();
          $("div.error").show();
            $("#error_message").addClass("error_msge");
        } else {
          $("div.error").hide();
            $("#error_message").removeClass("error_msge");
        }
      },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    },
    onkeyup: false,
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).addClass('errRed');
        $(element).addClass('text-error-red');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).removeClass('errRed');
        $(element).removeClass('text-error-red');
    },
    rules: {
        txt_Fname: "required",
        txt_lname: "required",
        txt_Mfname: "required",
        txt_Mlname: "required",
        txt_Pptnum: "required",
        txt_Pi: "required",
        txt_dob: "required",
        txt_Idt:"required",
        txt_Epdt:"required",
        sel_ms:"required",
        ipt_nation:"required",
        ipt_countryres:"required",            
        sel_rg:"required",
        sel_sem:"required",
        ipt_acdem:"required",
        gender:"required"
    }
});
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/xgLj3r32/4/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lots of issues and I strongly recommend that you [review the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

> But I am not getting when the user enter the value in the corresponding field the error count has to detect one by one for example If I have 5 fields are not entered by the user it should say You have missed 5 fields.

You have used the wrong option.  The `invalidHandler` only fires on an invalid form, so when there are zero errors your function will never be called and it will be stuck on show "1 error".  Use [the `showErrors` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) instead.

```
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1 ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted' : 'You have missed ' + errors + ' fields. Please fill before submitted.';
            $("#error_message").html(message);
            $(".error_msge").show();
            //$("div.error").show(); // superfluous
            //$("#error_message").addClass("error_msge"); // superfluous
        } else {
            $(".error_msge").hide();
            //$("div.error").hide(); // superfluous
            //$("#error_message").removeClass("error_msge"); // superfluous

        }
        // ensures that highlight/unhighlight will function
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
```

> Please fill before submitted. when all fields are entered the error field has to disable.

You forgot to hide the error message box when there are no errors: `$(".error_msge").hide()` was missing

> And I need to highlight the label of the radio input when nothing is selected.

You need a conditional inside the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions that will take care of this when the `element` is a `radio`.

```
    highlight: function (element) {
        if ($(element).is(':radio')) {
            $(element).siblings('label').addClass('errRed');
        } else {
            $(element).addClass('errRed');
        }
        $(element).prev('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-red').removeClass('text-error-black');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        if ($(element).is(':radio')) {
            $(element).siblings('label').removeClass('errRed');
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass('errRed');
        }
        $(element).prev('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-black').removeClass('text-error-red');
    }
```

I also moved the code for the asterisks in here since you want them to toggle color individually.

> More over I am trying to change my mandatory star from black to red.

Your CSS technique is flawed.  You are trying to select everything with the "black" class and simply add a "red" class, leaving you with two classes each with a different color.  Instead, you need to ***replace*** one class with the other class. Something like this...

```
$(".required-star").removeClass("text-error-red").addClass("text-error-black");
```

You need to programmatically trigger validation using the `.valid()` method when you use the date-picker...

```
$('.ipt_Field').on('change', function() {
    $("#basicForm").valid();
});
```

You do not need the `messages` option.  Since you are suppressing all of the messages, it's pointless.

Also do not leave the `errorPlacement` function empty.  Put a `return false` inside.

```
errorPlacement: function() {
    return false; // suppress error messages.
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/k5wxtmpL/**

Comment: Thank you so much for result I have one more query how to highlight the label of gender Kindly please suggest me

Comment: you are simply awesome man :) thank you so much you save my day

Comment: Hi Buddy once small request can you please tell me how to remove  the red star to black star when the user enter the each field

Comment: @Mahadevan, you would have to move those lines to the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions.

Comment: I am trying 

        highlight: function () {
            $(".required-star").removeClass("text-error-black").addClass("text-error-red");
        },
        unhighlight: function () {
            $(".required-star").removeClass("text-error-red").addClass("text-error-black");
        },

something like this

Comment: @Mahadevan, no.  You don't want to select and target them all at once.  You have to only target the closest one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87851/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-sparky).

Comment: hi @I am there chat room please join

Comment: @Mahadevan, answered new questions in chat and updated answer accordingly.